# 2nd interface not working

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp, interface

I have 2 interfaces. Direct ethernet connection as eth0 and a 4g dongle as eth1.

**# ip addr show**

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:ad:57:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.11/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8cce:6651:6412:c9e4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

14: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft 86387sec preferred_lft 75587sec
    inet6 fe80::e34a:4c22:2dbc:6444/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**# ip route show**

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.11 metric 202
default via 192.168.1.211 dev eth1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.100 metric 214
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.11 metric 202
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.100 metric 214
```

My goal is to use the dongle as a proxy server using 3proxy but the issue is that it's not working. I tested the dongle using curl and here are the results.

**What's working?**

```
curl ifconfig.me --interface eth0
curl ifconfig.me --interface eth1
curl ifconfig.me --interface 192.168.0.11
```

**What's not working? (The way I would like to use this interface)**

```
curl ifconfig.me --interface 192.168.1.100
```

How can I make my eth1 interface work using its local ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two default gateways at the same time. See your `ip route` command response. This never works properly except for the special iproute2 setting and separate routing tables for each interface when special conditions need to be defined.

Remove the default gateway of the first interface, and then very likely the `eth1` will start working. Or vice versa.

You can use both interfaces at the same time, but only with one default gateway in the system and with a routing table in which you describe exactly which remote networks should be routed through the `eth0` interface and which through `eth1`. Even so, under certain circumstances, there is a risk of so-called asymmetric routing.

### Edit

It is response to [Avinash Sah](https://askubuntu.com/users/1579971/avinash-sah) comments after my answer.

You do not give details of which networks you want to access through which interface, therefore my example of settings is not specific enough.

**Example 1**

Command to delete the default gateway for the `eth0` interface:

```
sudo ip route del default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

**Example 2**

Command to delete the default gateway for the `eth1` interface (delete only one default route, not both):

```
sudo ip route del default via 192.168.1.211 dev eth1
```

**Example 3**

Command to add new route for the `10.5.1.0/24` network using the `eth1` interface and router address `192.168.1.211` (i.e. next hop address):

```
sudo ip route add  10.5.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.211 dev eth1
```

**Important information**

All routing changes made using the `ip` command are made only in RAM and apply only until the system restarts, the interface is restarted, or the interface is disconnected and reconnected. This also gives the answer why the problem is restored by disconnecting and reconnecting the 4G dongle (`eth1`).

**Permanent solutions (use only one)**

1. Use the GUI to unset the default gateway to be added automatically using DHCP. Go to Settings --> Network --> Connection using eth0 --> IPv4 setting. Then switch off Automatic routing. Eventually add new routes (fill the rows in the table).
2. Create small script containing needed `ip ...` commands and set it to be executed after the boot.

**Note**
Creating additional routing tables with conditional routing rules using iproute2 is also possible, but it is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Also I noticed one thing. Whenever I remove and plug in the dongle, it again stops working. So if this is the correct way then is there any way to automate this? It works out on windows automatically. How can I add these rules automatically if this is the right way?

Comment: I have expanded the reply to respond to your comments.

Comment: Sorry, I need to see the diagram. I can't imagine your networking well.

Comment: Yes, it is more complicated, but the best I suppose. The conditions that apply to which routing rule must be well set to avoid rule collisions during routing or to prevent packets from being sent through the wrong interface.

Comment: OK. Does each dongle have only one network behind it? Does the connection to the Internet router and out into the public space lead through eth0?

Comment: each dongle has its own DHCP server running inside its firmware and yes, all traffic goes through eth0 (my main internet)

Comment: each dongle also has it's own different public IP and gateway

Comment: The DHCP server in the dongle must assign its clients 1) an IP address and 2) a gateway that is identical to the IP address of the interface eth1,eth2, etc. The PC will have only one default gateway through eth0 to the Internet. No further static routes are needed because the networks behind the interfaces eth1, eth2... are so-called directly connected networks that automatically have their entries in the routing table. If the hub also had the role of a router with its own IP address, the settings would have to look different.

Comment: so I just delete default routes for eth1, 2 etc?

Comment: Ah, so that's a completely different situation. In that case, you really need to have a set of routing tables, one for each dongle.

Comment: hmm, so I guess I should follow the blog and make a shell script that runs on reboots, and somehow when dongles are reconnected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137695/discussion-between-netbat-and-avinash-sah).

Comment: I have a question. How come `--interface eth1` work then? it works properly when I pass the interface name. I also tested on windows just now and both iface name and IP are working out of the box there